# Create standalone modal dialog service with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular2-services

I've been googling for a long time to investigate the way of creating dynamic dialog components in Angular 2. Almost all of them suggest the following:

1. Create a placeholder for a dynamic components.
2. Using `ComponentFactoryResolver` for dynamical creating components for displaying in opened dialog
3. Using `entryComponents` in app module for compliler to be aware of your custom component's factories

That is all great but in my project I have to implement a standalone modal service just like [shlomiassaf/angular2-modal](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal) or [angular2-material](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib/dialog) but without large amount of customizations and settings those libraries offer to end users. What could be the steps to create such functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to create a simple dialog box with angular 2 service. The main concept is to programmatically create an overlay then attach its `hostView` to application then append it to the `document.body`. Then create dialog box itself and using overlay reference append the dialog box to newly created overlay.

**Overlay**

```
import {
  Component,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  EventEmitter,
  Output,
  ViewChild,
  ViewContainerRef
} from "@angular/core";

@Component ({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: "dialog-overlay",
  template: `
    <div class="dialog-overlay" (click)="onOverlayClick($event)">
      <div #dialogPlaceholder ></div>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./overlay.component.css"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class OverlayComponent {
  @ViewChild("dialogPlaceholder", {read: ViewContainerRef})
  public dialogPlaceholder: ViewContainerRef;

  @Output()
  public overlayClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  public isOverlayOpen: boolean = false;

  public onOverlayClick($event: Event): void {
    const target: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement>$event.target;

    if (target.className.indexOf("dialog-overlay") !== -1) {
        this.overlayClick.emit();
    }
  }
}
```

Here we have a simple component with overlay styling (not included in the example) and a template variable `dialogPlaceholder` which we will use for placing our dialog box.

**Dialog component**

```
import {
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  HostBinding,
  Input,
  Output,
  ViewChild,
  ViewContainerRef,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy
} from "@angular/core";

@Component ({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: "dialog",
  template: `
    <div class="your-dialog-class">
      <div class="your-dialog-title-class">{{title}}</div>
      ... whatever
      <div #dynamicContent ></div>
      ... whatever
    </div>
  `
  styleUrls: ["./dialog.component.css"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class DialogComponent {
  @ViewChild("dynamicContent", {read: ViewContainerRef})
  public dynamicContent: ViewContainerRef;

  @Input()
  public isOpen: boolean = false;

  @Input()
  public title: string;

  @Output()
  public isOpenChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  public onCloseClick(event: Event): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.isOpenChange.emit(false);
  }
}
```

This component will be programmatically created with service and its `#dynamicContent` will be used as a placeholder for dialog content

**Service**

I won't include the whole listing of the service, only `create` method just to show the main concept of dynamically created dialogs

```
public create(content: Type<any>,
              params?: DialogParams): DialogService {
    if (this.dialogComponentRef) {
        this.closeDialog();
    }

    const dialogParams: DialogParams = Object.assign({}, this.dialogDefaultParams, params || {});
    const overlayFactory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(OverlayComponent);
    const dialogFactory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DialogComponent);

    // create an overlay
    this.overlayComponentRef = overlayFactory.create(this.injector);
    this.appRef.attachView(this.overlayComponentRef.hostView);
    this.document.body.appendChild(
      this.overlayComponentRef.location.nativeElement
    );
    this.overlayComponentRef.instance.isOverlayOpen = dialogParams.isModal;

    // create dialog box inside an overlay
    this.dialogComponentRef = this.overlayComponentRef
        .instance
        .dialogPlaceholder
        .createComponent(dialogFactory);
    this.applyParams(dialogParams);

    this.dialogComponentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

    // content
    this.contentRef = content ? this.attachContent(content, contentContext) : undefined;

    const subscription: Subscription = this.dialogComponentRef.instance.isOpenChange.subscribe(() => {
        this.closeDialog();
    });

    const overlaySubscription: Subscription = this.overlayComponentRef.instance.overlayClick.subscribe(() => {
        if (dialogParams.closeOnOverlayClick) {
            this.closeDialog();
        }
    });

    this.subscriptionsForClose.push(subscription);
    this.subscriptionsForClose.push(overlaySubscription);

    return this;
}

// this method takes a component class with its context and attaches it to dialog box
private attachContent(content: any,
                      context: {[key: string]: any} = undefined): ComponentRef<any> {
  const containerRef: ViewContainerRef = this.dialogComponentRef.instance.dynamicContent;
  const factory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(content);
  const componentRef: ComponentRef<any> = containerRef.createComponent(factory);

  this.applyParams(context, componentRef);
  componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

  const { instance } = componentRef;

  if (instance.closeEvent) {
    const subscription: Subscription = componentRef.instance.closeEvent.subscribe(() => {
        this.closeDialog();
    });

    this.subscriptionsForClose.push(subscription);
  }

    return componentRef;
}

// this method applies dialog parameters to dialog component.
private applyParams(inputs: {[key: string]: any}, component: ComponentRef<any> = this.dialogComponentRef): void {
    if (inputs) {
        const inputsKeys: Array<string> = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(inputs);

        inputsKeys.forEach((name: string) => {
            component.instance[name] = inputs[name];
        });
    }
}

public closeDialog(): void {
    this.subscriptionsForClose.forEach(sub => {
        sub.unsubscribe();
    });
    this.dialogComponentRef.destroy();
    this.overlayComponentRef.destroy();
    this.dialogComponentRef = undefined;
    this.overlayComponentRef = undefined;
}
```

Although this approach is much simpler than in `shlomiassaf/angular2-modal` or `angular2-material` it requires a lot of work to be done. The whole method of dynamically creating components in service violates the **separation of concerns** principle, however talking about dynamically created dialogs it is more handy to create them on the fly than keeping them somewhere in templates.

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate module in you application for handling some feature with component, service, directives...
In the end, you can just inject your module in main (root) module and start using like 3rd part library.

Great tutorial for handling that case is on this [LINK](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/feature-modules.html).